# Not getting any logs for node process running through pm2 in cluster mode

Tags: node.js, pm2, log4js-node

If I am running pm2 process for node js app in fork mode , The logs are getting generated but same app is not giving logs if running in pm2 cluster mode

I am using the below pm2 ecosystem file to start my app

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [
    {
    name: 'test',
    script: <entry_file_path>,
    exec_mode: "cluster",
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: false,
    combine_logs:true,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    exp_backoff_restart_delay: 1000,
    merge_logs: true,
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
  }]
};
```

I am using log4js v5.2.2 for logging in my node app

Comment: does [this](https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node/blob/master/docs/clustering.md) help?

Comment: @MAS tried adding pm2:true in log4js configuration and updated the log4js to latest version 6.x.x along with installing pm2-intercom but still can't see the logs

Comment: did you install pm2-intercom?

Comment: @MAS thanks! that link helped, I am now getting the logs

Comment: and it is working without pm2-intercom

Comment: glad it worked, anytime. Please answer your own question for others to see it.

Answer (score 3):

Based on suggestion of @MAS below configuration worked for me

run this command "pm2 install pm2-intercom" 
& then add pm2: true in log4js config

```
log4js.configure({
  appenders: { out: { type: 'stdout'}},
  categories: { default: { appenders: ['out'], level: 'info'}},
  pm2: true
});
```

for more details refer https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node/blob/master/docs/clustering.md